# Error de login con Api de facebook

Tags: sailsjs, facebook-api

Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer mi login con la `api` de facebook, pero cuando mando la petición al parecer al un problema con las `url` que agregué para que se realice el `callback`, estoy trabajando con `sails.js`usando el framework de `passport`, el error que me marca es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene idea de como solucionarlo se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo unico que me faltaba era agregar bien la redirección una vez que el servicio de facebook me diera un acceso, si se trabaja con `sails.js` de manera local, lo unico que tienes que hacer es colocar correctamente la `url` local para que redirecciones correctamente. Esto lo haces en la configuración de tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]